# Error using Levene test in R after a group by [error: is not a numeric variable]

Tags: r

I´m trying to use levene Test from "car" library in R with the iris dataset.

The code I have is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
iris %>% group_by (Species) %>% leveneTest( Sepal.Length )
```

From there I´m getting the following error:

```
Error in leveneTest.default(., Sepal.Length) : 
  . is not a numeric variable
```

I don´t know how to fix this, since the data types seem to be of the rigth type:

```
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For levene test, you need to specify a grouping factor, for example:

```
leveneTest(Sepal.Length ~ Species,data=iris)
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
       Df F value   Pr(>F)   
group   2  6.3527 0.002259 **
      147
```

This test whether the variances are homogenous across groups. It doesn't quite make sense for you to group them and do the leveneTest within the group. If you intend to do something else, you can elaborate more or comment.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
with(iris, leveneTest(Sepal.Length, Species))
```

maybe you are looking for such a solution

```
map(iris[, 1:4], ~ leveneTest(.x, iris$Species))
```